# How to run to parallel terminal windows? Linux

Tags: linux, shell, gnome, nohup, gnome-terminal

I'm looking to run two independent parallel gnome-terminal windows with some parameters, from 1 shell script.

so far I've got this:

```
#!/bin/sh
disown gnome-terminal -e window1.sh &
disown gnome-terminal -e window2.sh &
exit
```

Any ideas?
I've tried nohup too without success.

### FYI

Window[x].sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo window 
read -p
```

Comment: Why is `gnome-terminal -e window1.sh &` insufficient? Notice that `disown` doesn't work the way you expect it to work.

Comment: What about this isn't working?

Comment: The screen flashes with the two terminals, then they both just dissappear. I was expecting both to appear wait for key input, then continue working as normal terminal windows would.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
#bin/bash

prog="disown gnome-terminal -e window1.sh"
max=2
for i in $(seq $max); do
    if [ $i -lt $max ]; then
        exec $prog &> /dev/null &
    else
        exec $prog
    fi
done
```

Comment: Commands in variables is a bad idea. See [Bash FAQ 050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for discussion about this. What is that second (comment) line doing? Why are you using `exec` here? The one on the `&` line is pointless and the other one doesn't do very much for you.